# How do I design product and category tables in an Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: entity-relationship

I am designing an ERD. I am considering how I would link a `product entity` to a `category`
 I have two categories:

```
 1. BrandCategory (i.e. Apple, Nokia etc.)
 2. TypeCategory (Smartphone, Laptop, Tablet etc.)
```

A product can belong to a `BrandCategory` and a `TypeCategory.`

Can somoene advise me on how on how to link these up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is easy. First look at your objects:
P = Product, BC = BrandCategory, TC = TypeCategory

1) BC and TC are not related to each other.

2) P is related to TC. Lets look at the objects:

```
    P_1 ----> TC_1 (read as: Product_1 belongs to TypeCategory_1)
    P_2 ----> TC_1
    P_3 ----> TC_2
```

As we see, ONE product belongs to ONE typeCategory. And ONE typeCategory can have MANY products.

So we have a 1 to many relationship here.

[image]

Do the same for brandCategory. And the model should be complete.

But I suggest the you have inheritence here. You could model it with inheritance too, which could make more sense. Google for "Entity-Relationship" to get more info on that.

regards